# Why does gulp rewrite changes I have made to CSS?

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm working on a PHP/ Angular application, and want to reduce the column widths in a table displayed on one of the pages.

If I inspect the table in the browser, I can change the widths of the columns using their `width` attribute in the CSS in the 'Styles' tab of the developer console, and see the column widths adjusted appropriately. In  Atom (the IDE I'm using to develop the application), I opened the file where the the styles are defined (dashboard-rem.css), and made changes to the relevant values:

```
#fixPayerName {
    width: 24%;
}

#reduceWidthfirst {
    #width: 7.3%;
}

#reduceWidth-second {
    #width: 8%;
}
```

I then stopped my application from running, and recompiled the CSS using the commands `gulp` & `gulp pxtorem` from the path: workspace/project, which is how I always recompile the CSS any time it needs recompiling.

However, when I started my application up again using the commands `gulp copy:angular` & `ng build --watch --sourcemaps=false`, and viewed the page in the browser, the table column widths were all displayed exactly as they were before I changed & recompiled the CSS. I also noticed when looking at my IDE window again (which I hadn't closed at all), that the values in the CSS file I had just changed had changed back to what they were originally.

I changed them again, and then watched the IDE window while recompiling- it was at the point that I ran the first `gulp` command that the CSS variables reverted back to their original values.

Why is this happening? How can I make gulp keep the new values that I've set in the CSS?

Comment: are you sure you aren't changing the compiled file - the output, instead of the source file

Comment: Yep- turns out that was what I was doing... took me a while to realise. As you've probably guessed, I'm pretty new to gulp & these build tools.